# Meshing inconsistency

Tags: mesh-generation, mesh, gmsh

New to Gmsh. I am trying to create a very simple mesh that is essentially two cylinders merging into one.

So I added two parallel cylinders first (a bit farther from each other). Then I extruded (slanted) the right surface of each along with the circular boundaries. Then I translated everything of the bottom tube up so that the merge occurs.

Then when I do the meshing, as you can see from the attached picture, it does the meshing differently for the upper tube (beyond the extrusion) than the lower one. Why is it happening? Or is it inconsequential for any simulation afterwards?

[image]

Another question: when I do merging in this way, do the surfaces that fall inside the merged portion stay as surfaces or do they vanish automatically? If not, then how do I make them vanish?

Comment: I think you'll get a better answer on the [gmsh issue tracker](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/issues).